# How many pairs of image needed for training Siamese Network? And how to augment them?

Tags: deep-learning

Hi Deep Learning researchers and engineers,

Does anyone have experience in Siamese Network regarding the training data size? How many pairs of image do I need to train a Siamese Network?

And what kinds of data augmentation should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you find an answer for your question?

Comment: @Noran Sorry not yet. But I am using ~600 pairs and it looks good to me. The network used pretrained ResNet as backbone, which I think helped reduce the data needed.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question or updates since your last comment?